# How long is phone number token lifespan when we use ASP.NET Core identity?

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I use `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` for generating phone number token.
But I don't know how long is the phone number token lifespan and how can I change it ?